# How to combine/ add value of dictionairy keys and export to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary:

Input Dictionary

```
f = {
'10A7': [{'line_item_id': '837234000000089050',
   'item_id': '837234000000076055',
   'name': 'Potato',
   'quantity': 10.0}],

 '20A7': [{'line_item_id': '837234000000089027',
   'item_id': '837234000000076076',
   'name': 'Apple',
   'quantity': 10.0}, 

   {'line_item_id': '837234000000095018',
   'item_id': '837234000000076055',
   'name': 'Potato',
   'quantity': 10.0}]
}
```

I want to save the data of the above dictionary in CSV format.

**Expected Output**

Item,  10A7, 20A7, Total

Potato, 10, 10, 20

Apple, 0, 10, 10

Item is the list of unique names present in the dictionary(name).
Bill number is the key to the dictionary.
Total is the total count of each item in the row.

How to create the above data to CSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` for some manipulations

First we unwrap your dictionary in a line by line pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient = 'index').stack().reset_index()
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame.from_records(df[0].values)], axis=1).drop(columns = ['level_1',0])
df2
```

this generates

```
    level_0 line_item_id        item_id             name    quantity
0   10A7    837234000000089050  837234000000076055  Potato  10.0
1   20A7    837234000000089027  837234000000076076  Apple   10.0
2   20A7    837234000000095018  837234000000076055  Potato  10.0
```

Now we transform it to the aggegate view

```
df3 = df2.pivot(index = 'name', columns = 'level_0', values = 'quantity').fillna(0)
df3
```

produces

```
level_0 10A7    20A7
name        
Apple   0.0     10.0
Potato  10.0    10.0
```

now we add `'Total'` and save to csv

```
df3['Total'] = df3.sum(axis=1)
df3.to_csv('out.csv')
```

df3 now looks like this

```
level_0 10A7    20A7    Total
name            
Apple   0.0     10.0    10.0
Potato  10.0    10.0    20.0
```

Comment: @TanmayJain Great! Consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

then you can convert the dictionary to a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary)
```

then you can save the dataframe df to a csv file

```
df.to_csv(filename)
```

You can also try the answer in https://datatofish.com/dictionary-to-dataframe/